# ExtJS I don't understand the generated uri's from these proxies

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I just don't understand how ExtJS is building these routes, or how I can stop all of it.

For example, if I'm using a proxy like:

```
{
    type: 'rest',
    url: '/user',
    noCache: false,
    reader: { type: 'json', successProperty: 'success' }
}
```

I would **expect** requests like `GET /user` or `POST /user/123` as is the case with restfull apis.
 Instead I get stuff like `GET /user/root?node=root` or `GET user?page=1&start=0&limit=25`.

Is there a way to get ExtJS to stop adding all these extra params?

Comment: fyi, the examples of weird uri's mentioned are for separate stores; one extends a TreeStore, the other a normal Store. The former randomly tacks on a `/root?node=root` and the latter tacks on the `?page=1&start=0&limit=25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree store defines a default root id if you don't care of that yourself.

The page and start params are added by the paging toolbar in the grid. Your REST implementation should not be bothered by extra parameters. You can also disable them if you turn paging off.

Comment: Ya my implementation isn't really bothered by it... it's just ugly imo. Thanks for the help there, appreciated

Comment: How to turn off the root part of the request (not a parameter)? REST api expecting GET /controller instead of GET /controller/root?parameters. Thanks

Comment: You are either setting that in the store/proxy api or using a REST proxy in which case the server REST api should be expecting resource identifier. If you are not using REST on the backend don't use the REST proxy on the client either.